# @OneToMany typescript sequlize

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Я новичек в sequlize и я хотел бы понять почему @OneToMany в данном коде не связывает две таблицы
Модель 1

```
export class User extends Model<User> {
  @ApiProperty({
    example: '1',
    description: 'Уникальный идентификатор пользователя',
  })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Balance, (balance) => balance.creator)
  balance: Balance;

  @OneToMany(() => Balance, (balance) => balance.subscribers)
  subscriber: Balance;
}
```

И вторая таблица

```
export class Balance extends Model<Balance, BonusCreationAttributes> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.balance)
  creator: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.subscriber)
  subscribers: User[];
}
```

Я убрал лишние свойства чтобы было проще понять. Он должен связать balance - creator, и subscriber - subscribers

Comment: Как понять "связывает"? Как вы проверяете, что они не связались? Проверьте, правильно ли определены primary/foreign key у таблиц

Comment: @SiRanWeb смотрю через pgAdmin. Он показывает связи. А по поводу primary/foreign key как раз не понятно. Куда их отдавать в декораторах OneToOne, нужно ли создавать внешние ключи(я думал sequlize может их сам генерить), и если все нужно их прописывать можно ли сохранить работу как с обьектами(sql базово знаю, предполагаю что через джойны он может вытаскивать)? И можно ли допустим для связей не создавать их вручную, а взаимодействовать все же с обьектами? Простите что так много вопросов, просто реально новичек =)

Comment: Тут не могу точно ответить на все вопросы. Вам все же стоит глубже изучить документацию, в т.ч. раздел про [связи](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript#model-association). Обратите внимание на использование декоратора `@ForeignKey()` и поля, на которые он применяется.